# Error while doing sed editor

Tags: sed

```
sed -i -e "s/.*web_listen_uri.*/web_listen_uri = http://$staticip:9000/ g"
```

what is the problem in this string ? when executed it is showing this 
sed: -e expression #1, char 45: unknown option to `s'

I have tried with delimiters but still same error

Comment: You have to escape `/` in the replacement string.

Comment: Take a moment, look at the command. What do you see?

Comment: i tried to escape / but not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modify your `sed` command to `sed -i -e "s/.*web_listen_uri.*/web_listen_uri = http:\/\/$staticip:9000/g"`. And here's the example to use this command,

```
$ cat test
aaaaa web_listen_uri. bbbbb
$ sed -i -e "s/.*web_listen_uri.*/web_listen_uri = http:\/\/$staticip:9000/g" test
$ cat test 
web_listen_uri = http://192.168.1.1:9000
```

You need to escape `/`to`\/` for `sed` to be used.

Answer (score 0):

You have to escape `/` in the replacement string. Additionally, there is a space before the final `g` which might also be problematic.

Comment: actually i am new to this sed editor can you please tell me how to escape the / in the string

Comment: Use `\/`whenever you want to match `/`

Comment: Thanks for the answer